I am trying to make a navbar for a website , using HTML + Tailwindcss but the functionality i want is not happening
I tried the group-hover:block too but still when I hover over the solution and resources,  it's not showing the dropdown menu
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Front Page</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.0.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="bg-slate-600">
    <nav class="bg-white text-black h-12 flex items-center justify-between px-4">
      <div class="text-lg font-semibold">ABC Enterprises</div>
      <ul class="flex items-center space-x-4">
          <li class="relative group">
              <a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 font-bold rounded-md">Solutions</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content absolute hidden bg-white text-black py-2 rounded shadow-lg min-w-max top-full mt-1 group-hover:block">
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">ESG & Sustainability Reporting & Management</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Carbon Accounting & GHG Measurement</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Sustainable Procurement & Sourcing</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">ESG Portfolio Management For Investors</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">ESG Consulting</a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li class="relative group">
              <a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 font-bold rounded-md">Industries</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content absolute  bg-white text-black py-2 rounded shadow-lg min-w-max top-full mt-1 group-hover:block">
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Manufacturing</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Agri-business & Forestry</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Retail & Hospitality</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Health & Education</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Infrastructure</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Financial Institutions & Funds</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Real Estate & Construction</a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold">Sign In</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  </body>
  </html>
  


You are using an incorrect CDN. Go through the Tailwind CSS docs here.
Just replace this  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.0.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> with this <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
and your code should work just fine. Apply the same logic to all other list items.

There are no class define for group-hover:block in version 2.0.0 you need to upgrade with new version on Tailwind. As I have added new link of Tailwind <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Front Page</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-slate-600">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Front Page</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.0.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="bg-slate-600">
    <nav class="bg-white text-black h-12 flex items-center justify-between px-4">
      <div class="text-lg font-semibold">ABC Enterprises</div>
      <ul class="flex items-center space-x-4">
          <li class="relative group">
              <a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 font-bold rounded-md">Solutions</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content absolute hidden bg-white text-black py-2 rounded shadow-lg min-w-max top-full mt-1 group-hover:block">
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">ESG & Sustainability Reporting & Management</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Carbon Accounting & GHG Measurement</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Sustainable Procurement & Sourcing</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">ESG Portfolio Management For Investors</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">ESG Consulting</a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li class="relative group">
              <a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 font-bold rounded-md">Industries</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content absolute  bg-white text-black py-2 rounded shadow-lg min-w-max top-full mt-1 hidden group-hover:block">
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Manufacturing</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Agri-business & Forestry</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Retail & Hospitality</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Health & Education</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Infrastructure</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Financial Institutions & Funds</a>
                  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-1 hover:bg-gray-100">Real Estate & Construction</a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text-black hover:text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold">Sign In</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  </body>
  </html>
  
</body>
</html>



